# Second attempt at canvas spatial grid collision

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

After posting my first question and my first attempt which you can see here:

[Canvas spatial grid collision](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23095/my-first-attempt-at-canvas-spatial-grid-collision-please-be-honest)

I have re-written it to try and implement what the person gave as an answer. I didn't do the `prototype` method as it was overkill for this and besides I am saving that for my next project!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var canvas = $('canvas')[0]; // canvas object
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // canvas context
    var engine = new engine(new grid(new block().getSize())); // run the game

    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressDown, true); // event listener for keydown
    function keyPressDown(evt) {
        if(engine.activeBlock) { // block is falling
            switch(evt.keyCode) {
                case 37: // left arrow
                    engine.pressLeft();
                break;
                case 39: // right arrow
                    engine.pressRight();
                break;
                case 40: // down arrow
                    engine.activeBlock.pressDown();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyPressUp, true); // event listener for keyup
    function keyPressUp(evt) {
        if(engine.activeBlock) { // block is falling
            switch(evt.keyCode) {
                case 40:
                    engine.activeBlock.releaseDown();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // block object
    function block() {
        this.x = 500; // x coord
        this.y = 0; // y coord
        this.size = 50; // size of block squared
        this.getSize = function() { // returns size of the block
            return this.size;
        };
        this.baseVelocity = 1; // base speed
        this.velocity = this.baseVelocity; // current speed
        this.genColor = function() { // random block color
            var colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'fuchsia'];
            return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        };
        this.color = this.genColor(); // blocks color
        this.update = function() { // update blocks position
            this.y += this.velocity;
        };
        this.pressDown = function() { // key press down
            this.velocity += 1;
        };
        this.releaseDown = function() { // key release down
            this.velocity = this.baseVelocity;
        };
        this.moveLeft = function() {
            this.x -= this.size;
        };
        this.moveRight = function() {
            this.x += this.size;
        };
    }
    // grid object
    function grid(blockSize) {
        this.cellSize = blockSize; // cell size of grid
        this.cellsX = canvas.width / this.cellSize; // cells along x axis
        this.cellsY = canvas.height / this.cellSize; // cells along y axis
        this.buildGrid = function() { // returns built grid
            var arr = new Array(this.cellsX);
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
                arr[i] = new Array(this.cellsY);
            }
            return arr;
        };
        this.arr = this.buildGrid(); // holds grid
        this.getCoords = function(i) { // get relevant grid coords
            return Math.floor(i / this.cellSize);
        };
        this.checkDown = function(block) { // check grid for collisions down
            if(this.getCoords(block.y) == (this.cellsY - 1)) { // block has hit bottom of canvas
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x)][this.getCoords(block.y) + 1]) { // block has landed on top of another block
                return true;
            }
        };
        this.checkLeft = function(block) { // check grid for collisions left
            if(this.getCoords(block.x) <= 0) { // block has hit left edge
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x) - 1][this.getCoords(block.y)]) { // block is on left
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x) - 1][this.getCoords(block.y) - 1]) { // block is on left
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x) - 1][this.getCoords(block.y) + 1]) { // block is on left
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        this.checkRight = function(block) { // check grid for collisions right
            if(this.getCoords(block.x) >= (this.cellsX - 1)) {
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x) + 1][this.getCoords(block.y)]) {
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x) + 1][this.getCoords(block.y) - 1]) {
                return true;
            } else if(this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x) + 1][this.getCoords(block.y) + 1]) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        this.storeBlock = function(block) { // store block in grid
            block.x = this.cellSize * Math.floor(block.x / this.cellSize); // floor x coord to nearest cellSize multiple
            block.y = this.cellSize * Math.floor(block.y / this.cellSize); // floor y coord to nearest cellSize multiple
            this.arr[this.getCoords(block.x)][this.getCoords(block.y)] = block;
        };
    }
    // engine object
    function engine(grid) {
        this.framerate = 20; // framerate
        this.activeBlock = new block(); // active block
        this.nextBlock = new block(); // next block
        this.drawBlock = function(block) { // draw block onto canvas
            ctx.fillStyle = block.color;
            ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.size, block.size);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
            ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.size, block.size);
            ctx.fillStyle = block.color;
            ctx.fillRect(block.x + (block.size / 10), block.y + (block.size / 10), block.size - ((block.size / 10) * 2), block.size - ((block.size / 10) * 2));
        };
        this.drawGrid = function() { // draw existing blocks stored in grid
            for(var i = 0; i < grid.arr.length; ++i) {
                for(var i2 = 0; i2 < grid.arr[i].length; ++i2) {
                    if(grid.arr[i][i2]) {
                        this.drawBlock(grid.arr[i][i2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        this.pressLeft = function() { // press left
            if(!grid.checkLeft(this.activeBlock)) { // check grid collision
                this.activeBlock.moveLeft(); // move left
            }
        };
        this.pressRight = function() { // press right
            if(!grid.checkRight(this.activeBlock)) { // check grid collision
                this.activeBlock.moveRight(); // move right
            }
        };
        this.resetCanvas = function() { // reset canvas background
            ctx.fillStyle = '#eee';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        };
        this.loop = function() { // the loop
            this.resetCanvas();
            this.drawGrid();
            this.drawBlock(this.activeBlock);
            this.activeBlock.update();
            if(grid.checkDown(this.activeBlock)) { // check grid collision down
                grid.storeBlock(this.activeBlock); // store block in grid
                this.activeBlock = this.nextBlock;
                this.nextBlock = new block();
            }
        };
        this.run = function() { // set interval
            setInterval(this.loop.bind(this), this.framerate); // bind the loop
        };
        this.run(); // run on instance
    }
});
```

Are there any more improvements that I could change to this? Any best practices that I haven't done?

You can view what the code does [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ShaShads/LM3PN/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a general point to consider, you're making *everything* public. Consider your Block

```
function block() {
    this.x = 500; // x coord
    this.y = 0; // y coord
    this.size = 50; // size of block squared
    this.getSize = function() { // returns size of the block
        return this.size;
    };
}
```

Do you want someone to be able to change the size of your block? It doesn't look like you do.

```
var b = new block();
b.size = -5 // I'm pretty sure you don't want this to be possible.
```

Consider only making things public if you want other parts of your script to be able to change it.

```
function Block() {
    this.x = 500;
    this.y = 0; 
    var size = 50; 
    this.getSize = function() { 
        return size;
    };
}

var b = new Block();
b.size // doesn't exist -> people have to use getSize function.
```

Thinking about it fully, you'd probably want your x and y coordinates to be private too - it should only be possible to update it via your update function. If you're interested, check out this page: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Thanks my first game I coded like this was in java for android and was pretty basic, guess I didn't think about the differences coding in javascript which is available client side.

Comment: @ShaShads it's a pretty good effort :). Another small point would be your keyPressUp function, there's no point in using a switch statement if you only care about one possible value. Also, you need to check `evt.which` as well as `evt.keyCode` as some browsers use one and not the other.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't even notice that about the `keyPressUp` function, I can guarantee that I copy/pasted it in a hurry to see if it worked from the `keyDown` functions!! Thanks buddy you have been a great help :)

Comment: @ShaShads looks like I was getting confused with jQuery about the event.which: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471691/1402923. No problem, have fun!